# Javascript: link to anchor in hidden container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have links in a container with anchors in another container hidden by default.
When both container are showing, the link works without problem, but when the "Anchors" container is hidden, the link does not work.

What I would like to do : on the click of the link, show the relative container and go to the line of the anchor.

Here is what I did, without much success ([also as a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqsv1b29/14/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle > *").hide();
  $(".toggle .header").show();
  $(".toggle .header").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().not(".header, .wy-table-responsive").toggle(400);
    $(this).parent().children(".wy-table-responsive").children().toggle(400);
    $(this).parent().children(".header").toggleClass("open");
    $(this).parent().children(".wy-table-responsive").toggleClass("open");
  });

  // Add click event listeners to links with href pointing to anchors in hidden section
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior of link
    var targetId = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); // Get the id of the target anchor
    $(document.location.targetId).slideDown().prev().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle .header {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.toggle .header p:before {
  content: " ▶ ";
}

.toggle .header.open p:before {
  content: " ▼ ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle docutils container">
  <div class="header docutils container">
    <p><strong>Keywords</strong></p>
  </div>
  <pre class="literal-block">
<a class="reference internal" href="#ref1"><span class="std std-ref">ref1</span></a> value = 1
<a class="reference internal" href="#ref2"><span class="std std-ref">is_planar</span></a>  value= 2
</pre>
</div>

<div class="toggle docutils container">
  <div class="header docutils container">
    <p><strong>Anchors</strong></p>
  </div>
  <p id="ref1">ref1 anchor
    <p id="ref2">ref2 anchor
</div>
```

Comment: The code you have shown above, does not currently match what your jsfiddle contains. In your fiddle, you have `var $toggleContainer = $(".toggle");` - but that of course selects _all_ the elements with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there were a couple of relatively-minor problems:

1. You were removing the `#` from `targetId`, but if you're going to use it with `$()` to look something up by ID, you need that as it's what indicates an ID selector.
2. `$(document.location.targetId)` looks for a property called `targetId` on `document.location`, then uses its value as the argument to `$`. I think you wanted to just use the `targetId` variable you'd just created and filled in.
3. You weren't actually scrolling to anything, just sliding it down.

I've fixed that below by not stripping the `#`, just using `$(targetId)` to get the element, and using the completion callback for [`slideDown`](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/#slideDown-duration-complete) to scroll the target into view (using the built-in "smooth" animation):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle > *").hide();
  $(".toggle .header").show();
  $(".toggle .header").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().not(".header, .wy-table-responsive").toggle(400);
    $(this).parent().children(".wy-table-responsive").children().toggle(400);
    $(this).parent().children(".header").toggleClass("open");
    $(this).parent().children(".wy-table-responsive").toggleClass("open");
  });

  // Add click event listeners to links with href pointing to anchors in hidden section
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior of link
    var targetId = $(this).attr("href"); // Get the id of the target anchor
    var target = $(targetId);
    target
      .slideDown(() => {
        target[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      })
      .prev()
      .addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle .header {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.toggle .header p:before {
  content: " ▶ ";
}

.toggle .header.open p:before {
  content: " ▼ ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle docutils container">
  <div class="header docutils container">
    <p><strong>Keywords</strong></p>
  </div>
  <pre class="literal-block">
<a class="reference internal" href="#ref1"><span class="std std-ref">ref1</span></a> value = 1
<a class="reference internal" href="#ref2"><span class="std std-ref">is_planar</span></a>  value= 2
</pre>
</div>

<div style="height: 50em">A bunch of space so we can see scrolling</div>

<div class="toggle docutils container">
  <div class="header docutils container">
    <p><strong>Anchors</strong></p>
  </div>
  <p id="ref1">ref1 anchor</p>
  <p id="ref2">ref2 anchor</p>
</div>
```

I also inserted an element between them so we could see the scrolling.

(Also, you weren't closing your paragraphs tags. I realize you don't *have* to much of the time, but it messes with formatters [and with the minds of other people reading your code], I suggest doing it. I've done it above.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! is there a way to make the whole "Anchors" container visible and not only the line of the anchor ?

Comment: @GMV871 - Do you want all of the anchors shown, or just the referenced one?

Comment: all the Anchors container should be shown , but I think I figure it out adding `.parents(".toggle ").find("> *")`  before `.slideDown`. Now the last point, when the Anchor is toggled the small triangle on the left does not change from " ▶ " to " ▼ ". Like it does for the Keywords section. Any Ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: @GMV871 - You can do it by adding `target.closest(".toggle").find(".header").addClass("open");`. But I would recommend completely changing how this works, and driving it based on the `<div class="toggle docutils container">` and without doing any hiding/showing directly in the JavaScript. Instead, default the relevant children to hidden in the CSS, and then add the `open` class to that `div` (not the header). Use CSS triggered by that class to show the children and change the `::before` pseudo-element on `.header`. It'll be less code, and more reliable. (I don't have time to do it right now.)